# JS Facebook API error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

In the following code, user is redirected to the current page (dashboard) after logging in using Facebook JS-SDK from login page(fb-login.html)

But when I call `FB.api()` it generates the error: `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user` although the `access_token` is passed to the `FB.api` as shown below.

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, {  access_token : accessToken } ,function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

As you can see the `accessToken` is being passed so I am not sure why this error.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>App Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is Your Dashboard.</p>

    <div class="form-line">
      <button type="button" name="btn-fb-login" id="btn-fb-logout" value="FB Log Out">FB Login Out</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  <script>    
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
           var accessToken;
           var uID;

           FB.init({
             appId      : '1910xxxxxxxxxxx',
             cookie     : true,
             xfbml      : true,
             version    : 'v2.8'
           });
           FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

           FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
            if(!(response.status === 'connected')){
                location.href = './fb-login.html';
                } else {
                    uID = response.authResponse.userID;
                    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                }

            });

            console.log(FB.getAuthResponse());

            FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, {  access_token : accessToken } ,function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }


        var btn = document.getElementById('btn-fb-logout');
        btn.onclick = function(){
            FB.logout()
            location.href = './fb-login.html';
        }

    </script>
```

Pls take a look and suggest an appropriate solution. 
Thanks
dk

Answer (score 1):

Moved `FB.api(...)` inside `else { uID = response.authResponse.userID; accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;}` and that worked.